Enable enable_repartition_joins in CItus
I was running some SQL query and got the error:
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) the query contains a join that requires repartitioning HINT:  Set citus.enable_repartition_joins to on to enable repartitioning
So, I tried enabling enable_repartition_joins in citus using:
SET citus.enable_repartition_joins = on;
but when I run SHOW citus.enable_repartition_joins; it results off.
Any possible reason why could this be happening?
Tried Methods:

Restarting Postgres didn't help.
The queries don't show any error while execution.
The user is "postgres" i.e super admin
postgres  -c "psql -p 9700 -U postgres -c 'SET citus.enable_repartition_joins = on;'" Tried this command as well.

